# Using sqlalchemy to generate: SELECT * ... INTO OUTFILE "file";

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, into-outfile

I have recently started using SQLALCHEMY to query a my-sql database. I want to generate a select statement that uses the "`INTO OUTFILE <file>`" syntax to export query results to a test file. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/export.txt';
```

Is there a way to generate the "`INTO OUTFILE...`" clause using SQLALCHEMY?

If not, can I subclass one of the SQLALCHEMY classes so I can build that clause myself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some thinking and poking around the examples on the SQLAlchemy site and figured it out. (Also posted to [sql-alchemy user reciptes](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/SelectIntoOutfile))

---

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import Executable, ClauseElement
from sqlalchemy.ext import compiler

class SelectIntoOutfile(Executable, ClauseElement):
    def __init__(self, select, file):
        self.select = select
        self.file = file


@compiler.compiles(SelectIntoOutfile)
def compile(element, compiler, **kw):
    return "%s INTO OUTFILE '%s'" % (
        compiler.process(element.select), element.file
    )


e = SelectIntoOutfile(select([s.dim_date_table]).where(s.dim_date_table.c.Year==2009), '/tmp/test.txt')
print e
eng.execute(e)
```